# Maven: Can I speed up mvn site?

Tags: maven, apt

Is there a quicker way to generate a site for maven for preview?

Background:

I'm using mvn site to generate a website which includes documentation for our project.  I'm using the the apt format, which is simple, and very few mistakes are actually made, but I do want feedback after adding large amount of content so I don't have to spend too much time searching for syntax errors.

The problem is the site takes about 2 minutes to generate each time, and I would like quicker feedback then this for how the site looks and if I made any mistakes while typing up the docs.  This isn't a huge issue but, the situation could certainly be improved.

Also, in order to help me out I'm using vim with syntax highlighting and if I need to get a quick preview on something there was a nice plug-in for eclipse that allows me to preview whether or not my apt is working correctly (of course, it's not the same as what is generated by maven, but it's close enough).

I'm open to any other suggestions, but generating a quick preview with maven would be the best option for productivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure the 'reporting' section to turn off what you don't want. Dependency analysis, for example, takes a long time. Look at the doc for the project-info-reports-plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I found a convenience parameter in the site plugin generateReports that can be set to false to turn off all report generation.  It takes 8 seconds instead of 2 minutes to create the site! :)

Comment: Happy. For completeness, `mvn -DgenerateReports=false site`. Very happy